# Springboot criteria query, performing join operation on one-to-many relationship?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We have two tables. First one Transaction and the other transaction status with one to many relationship, as in one transaction can have multiple status like "Pending", "failed", "Completed" across different timelines.

So I want to create a criteria query api, which will fetch all the transactions whose status are "Pending", and also that status is the latest one ie, it should not fetch transaction who have 2 status lets say pending and then a completed, but fetch only those whose latest status is "pending".

Transaction table has fields like : id, credId, debtId, amount, charges etc + onetomany status relation.
Transaction status has filed : id, transactionId, status, created.

Note: I am joining two tabled based on transaction id.

I have tried using normal JPA queries, but as we are switching to criteria queries, we want to make everything dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it myself. The code below should explain itself.

```
Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
            Root<TransactionStatus> subRoot = subquery.from(TransactionStatus.class);

            subquery.select(cb.max(subRoot.get("id")));
            subquery.groupBy(subRoot.get("TransactionId"));
            subquery.where(cb.equal(subRoot.get("TransactionId"), requests.get("id")));

            Join<Transaction, TransactionStatus> joinCourse = requests.join("statuses", JoinType.INNER);
            predicates.add(cb.equal(joinCourse.get("id"), (subquery)));
            predicates.add(cb.equal(joinCourse.get("status"), requestsPayload.getStatus()));
```